# can the value of x change in a turn

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I have a card that gives x power to a creature until end of turn, where x is the number of creature cards in the graveyard. And then I take back a creature card from my graveyard using some effect. Does the value of x change along with it?

Comment: [Ghoul's Feast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=338407), perhaps? You'll usually get better answers if you name the card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

> 611.2d If a resolving spell or ability that creates a continuous effect contains a variable such as X, the value of that variable is determined only once, on resolution.

Because you said "until end of turn", I'm assuming that you are talking about casting a spell or activating an ability that has such text, in which case this applies. See [Strength of Cedars](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Strength%20of%20Cedars).

Note that if you have a permanent on the battlefield that says "creatures you have get +x/0, where x is the number of creature cards in your graveyard", then it is a static ability, and the value of x will change every time your graveyard changes. See [Wreath of Geists](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wreath%20of%20Geists).